# Suave Web Application running on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, suave

I'm looking for a simple 'Hello, World" example of Suave running on Ubuntu. I have tried looking all over the net to no avail

Comment: All you need to do is have nginx act as a forward proxy to your running suave app.

Comment: You don't "need" to do this - but it's a recommended approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to get it up and running on Xubuntu 16.04. I am using dotnet core and visual studio code.

To the best of my memory :) :

Install dot net core (from https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#ubuntu)

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net/repos/dotnet/ xenial main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list'

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver apt-mo.trafficmanager.net --recv-keys 417A0893

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install dotnet-dev-1.0.0-preview2-003121
```

Then install visual studio code:
https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/?dv=linux64_deb

Add ionide extension for syntax highlight etc.
In VS Code Ctrl + P - ext install ionide-fsharp

Then in terminal (will create a blank Fsharp project):

```
mkdir hwapp

cd hwapp

dotnet new --lang f#
```

Then add suave to project.json file:

```
"dependencies": {

    "Microsoft.FSharp.Core.netcore": "1.0.0-alpha-160509",

    "Suave": "2.0.0-alpha4",

    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {

  "type": "platform",

  "version": "1.0.0"

}
```

Then the standard suave helloworld should work in Program.fs

```
open Suave

startWebServer defaultConfig (Successful.OK "Hello World!")
```